RPI4 communication with RS422 with USB
Im'y trying to add a kind of "closed loop software control" on a small CNC.
I use a RPI4 to control the motors' drivers,
I added a YH800-3P counter (Digital Read Out system from YHSINO) and some ka-300 optical rulers (closed linear grating scales from Sino) to double check,
And yes, the motors are not precise enough.
So now I want to link the ka-300 optical ruler to my RPI4,
And I'm using a RS422 to USB converter (the US-270 from brainboxes). Using USB-A connector
But so far no results :)
I tried like this :
stephane@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05d1:1019 Brainboxes, Ltd USB2Serial 1xRS422/485

stephane@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | grep ttyUSB
[    8.248260] usb 1-1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0

import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',  
    baudrate=115200,        # Tried also 9600
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    timeout=1             
)

def read_encoder():
    if ser.is_open:
        print("Serial port open, waiting for datas...")
        data = ser.read(10)  
        for i in range(1, 10):
            if data:
                print(f"Received datas : {data}")
            else:
                print("No data received.")
            time.sleep(1)
            i += 1
    else:
        print("Serial port not opened.")

read_encoder()

And here is the result I had :
Serial port open, waiting for datas...
No data received.
No data received.
No data received.
No data received.
No data received.
No data received.
No data received.
No data received.
No data received.  

Of course, if I plus the RS422 connector directly in the YH800-3P DRO it works fine ^^
But I think I really need the data on my RPI :)
Hay anybody tried yet something like this ?
Thanks a lot for your reading time !
